# Mail has been Sent But does not received

Tags: c#, email, iis, asp.net-web-api, smtp

I am struggling almost a week for this issue. this is my code

```
public string GenerateEmail(EmailConfigDetail emailConfig)
    {
        MailMessage mailMessage = new MailMessage();
        try
        {
            if (emailConfig != null)
            {
                fromMailId = emailConfig.fromMailId;
                toMailId = emailConfig.toMailId;
                hostAddress = emailConfig.hostAddress;
                Body = emailConfig.Body;
                subject = emailConfig.subject;
                attachmentPath = emailConfig.AttachmentFilePath;
            }


            mailMessage.To.Add(toMailId);
            mailMessage.From = new MailAddress(fromMailId);
            mailMessage.Subject = subject;
            mailMessage.Body = Body;
            mailMessage.IsBodyHtml = true;
            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(attachmentPath))
            {
                Attachment attachment = new Attachment(attachmentPath, MediaTypeNames.Application.Pdf);
                //ContentDisposition disposition = attachment.ContentDisposition;
                string guid = attachment.Name.Split('_')[2];
                attachment.Name = attachment.Name.Replace('_' + guid, string.Empty);
                mailMessage.Attachments.Add(attachment);
            }

            SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
            smtp.Host = hostAddress;
            smtp.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential();
            smtp.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
            smtp.EnableSsl = true;
            ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback =
              delegate (object s, X509Certificate certificate, X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors)
              { return true; };

            smtp.Send(mailMessage);
            DisposeMailAttachments(mailMessage);
            retVal = "Email sent successfully";
            return retVal;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            DisposeMailAttachments(mailMessage);
            throw ex;
        }
        finally
        {
            DisposeMailAttachments(mailMessage);
        }

    }
```

My above code is working fine while am sending mail. And I got a exact message `"Email sent successfully";` without any error. but I am not able to receive any mail in my to address.  I have asked my admin team and support team. they are telling no issues in their  side. Could you please suggest me if i am missing anything.

```
From address: no-reply@mydomain.com
To Address: ramesh.rajendran@mydomain.com
```

Comment: `smtp.Send()` throws an exception if there is some error with the message, smtp-configuration or recipients list. (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/swas0fwc(v=vs.110).aspx) If there is no exception, the issue is on the server side (either sending or receiving). Maybe it's qualified as spam? Btw. if you use `try .. catch .. finally` you only need to call `DisposeMailAttachments` in the `finally` block, as it's always executed

Comment: Check if mx records are set properly for the domain you are sending to. are you able to send email manually to that sender ?

Comment: @mdeora Yes. I can send it manually to the sender.

Comment: Just for testing, try without ServerCertificateValidationCallback  and see if it works or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's working fine if I am disable the SSL

`smtp.EnableSsl = false;`